# C++ file on visual studio is missing or invalid

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio

I am using Ubuntu currently and trying to launch a c++ file through visual studio (code). The code for the file itself is very simple (just a hello world program):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello cd World!";
    return 0;
}
```

When launching the code through just pressing f5 it says the file quote: "is missing or invalid." It links me to the launch.json file which tells me to change the path. After doing so it tells me the same thing of: "missing or invalid file" but before it states the path to the file: '/home/taka/VSCode/Hello_World' which is correct. I have tried adding a .cpp to the end but it does not find the file that is there. Below is going to be the code of the json file which it asks to edit.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Hello_World",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        },
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        "windows": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "C++ Attach (GDB)",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Hello_World",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "processId": "${command.pickProcess}",
        "externalConsole": false,
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        },
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        "windows": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Don't post a picture of the code, post the code.

Comment: would you like me to change it or just a recommendation for my next post ?

Comment: I would change it. People not being able to copy/paste the problematic line lowers your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: It also makes the post content unindexable and is generally not in keeping with various paradigms of this site.

Comment: ok, give me a sec :p

Comment: Have you compiled the code, before to launch it?

Comment: i thought it does everything as you pres f5 if not i have not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution which i have tried is to compile and run using the terminal but write the code itself inside the IDE. Its a bandage solution but it does work.

If someone else ever wants to compile something in ubuntu console use:
g++ name_of_file.cpp
then ./name_of_file.out to run

Comment: ended up using netbeans instead as it actually worked on install :)